# How to set up a server for android app?

Tags: android, database, webserver

I am trying to create an android application in which an user will pretty save some data in database-like user data, photos and also be able to retrieve.

But I am clueless how to set up a server, connect to some database etc.

Can somebody help me point to right resources for end-to-end installation of server, database, and its interaction with the android application

Comment: set up server means , your trying to use the android database data in web browser ? something like this ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are mobile app developer and want to create server-client app then better use any back-end service rather than implementing new by own. Some most advanced and simple to use services are [Parse](https://developers.facebook.com/products/parse) and [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) , [BaasBox](http://www.baasbox.com/) also there are many more.

And the plus point is this services free of cost until you have very large users.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a basic server that works over HTTP, and use HTTP libraries for android to make requests and handle results in the device. There are plenty of technologies with which you could make the server, just google building REST API with PHP/.net/java (whichever language you are comfortable with).